# Is it Possible to apply styles for tab titles

Tags: android, tabs, styles

In my tab layout i have 3 tabs.Title of this tabs are default all in caps i want to apply styles like Bole,Italic and font size to tabs differently is it possible.
I am using tab layout and view pager with NoActionBar as style.

Comment: yes ..its possible

Comment: can you post the answer.How we can apply these styles?

Comment: sure..just give me few minutes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to apply styles to the default Tabs title.Following link will be help you for creating custom tabs.

http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-tab-layout-in-android/28153

Comment: That link is very useful to create custom tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just follow this

`custom_tab_item`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="@dimen/tab_label"/>
```

`main_layout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:text="Toolbar Title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

`Activity`:

```
    public class DiningActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dining);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title)).setText(R.string.dining);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        setupTabs();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new RestaurantFragment(), getString(R.string.restaurants));
        adapter.addFragment(new HotelsFragment(), getString(R.string.hotels));
        adapter.addFragment(new BarsPubsFragment(), getString(R.string.bars_pubs));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setupTabs() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
        tabOne.setText(getString(R.string.restaurants));
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
        tabTwo.setText(getString(R.string.hotels));
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

        TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
        tabThree.setText(getString(R.string.bars_pubs));
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(Numerics.TWO).setCustomView(tabThree);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: If we want apply any sizes and style we can mention in custom_tab_item.layout.I understand that is it Right or Wrong?

Comment: i try to create example by using ur code but i am geting null point error for tabsetup.

Comment: is it not possible to apply styles for default tabs with out using customized tabs.

Answer (score 0):

inside android.support.design.widget.TabLayout set theme attribute like this

```
   android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout"
```

and define  theme in style

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Comment: it is not working style is applied for text in tabs not Tab Titles.I want apply style to **Tab Title**.